# Why rvm install 2.0.0 asks for sudo password?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby 2.0.0-p247 through rvm. But, it is asking for password. Is it normal to provide sudo password? I've not configured sudo password in sudoers file. I'm using Oracle Enterprise Linux 6 x64 .

Comment: Generally, yes, that’s normal, if you’re installing Ruby system-wide.

Comment: *ONLY* if you're installing Ruby system-wide. A normal installation of RVM is for a single-user only, and will never need `sudo`, ever.

Answer (score 10):

The `sudo` is for [autolibs](http://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs) - which means RVM will install the required software like `openssh` or `libyaml` which are required for standard ruby to work properly.

You can change the `autolibs` to see the required packages instead of installing them:

```
rvm autolibs read-fail
```

and to get back to the default which installs requirements:

```
rvm autolibs reset
```

Comment: I understood rvm is aksing for sudo password as it wants to install the required dependency. I can use `rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=0`. But, it will install ruby without required packages. And, it will create issues in the time of rails and bundle installation. I am installing ruby as a normal user. Should I add my username in the sudoers file and proceed ahead? Will it create any problem post installation?

Comment: there are two options for adding to sudoers file, you can either add yourself to be allowed to execute `sudo` at all and you can set NOPASWD for yourself to not have to type password, on your real system (development machine) you should use first option, on virtual machines/vagrant you can add `NOPASSWD` as those systems are isolated a lot better from internet.

Comment: So, as I understood, `rmv install 2.0.0` has be executed with sudo priviledge to install required dependecy.

Comment: check the answer from @the-tin-man - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19083977/497756 - you should not prefix `rvm` with `sudo`, when it is needed rvm will call `sudo` internally and only then ask you for password.

Answer (score 2):

This is from [the RVM documentation](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) for multiple user installations:

> However, once the install is complete, and the instructions to add users to the rvm group is followed, the use of either sudo or rvmsudo is no longer required. The 'sudo' command is only to temporarily elevate privileges so the installer can complete it's work. If you need to use 'sudo' or 'rvmsudo' after the install is complete, some part of the install directions were not properly followed. This usually is because people execute the install as root, rather than executing the installation instructions from a non-privileged user account.

Those last two sentences are very important.

RVM is designed to be used as a single-user tool, installed in their home directory, and, if installed that way *NEVER* needs `sudo` to run or install or change anything, nor will the user ever have to do things as root.

The "Troubleshooting Your Install" section in [the installation documentation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) is a good starting point for you.

Answer (score -7):

Just do "sudo rvm ...." then type in your password